# ubuntu how to copy downloaded files

Tags: ubuntu

I am new to ubuntu, starting today.

I am trying to setup cassandra database in desktop version.

I downloaded and extracted files into downloads folder.

Now i want to copy files to /Cassandra folder under root. I don't want it to be in downloads folder.

Problem is through UI i am not able to access cassandra folder. 
And through terminal i can't access downloads folder.

How to move around files either in terminal or UI without this folder security issues. How does it suppose to be used?

Comment: What happens when you try to access the downloads folder through the terminal? Show *exactly* the commands you use and the error messages you receive.

Comment: i can't even go to that folder, using cd command

Answer (score 2):

You're gonna want this in your home directory, not root.  Build it from there as a normal user, but if you do a `make install`, run that as `sudo make install` instead so that you will install it as user `root`.  Run the following commands in a shell script, or if you want to do it interactively, type each line separately (omitting the first line that begins with the # in it).

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo mv /root/Cassandra ~/
sudo chown -R `whoami`:`whoami` ~/Cassandra
sudo chmod -R ug+rw ~/Cassandra
```

Comment: If he does type the hashbang line, it'll just be a comment. :)

Comment: meh, true.  But better to save a few keystrokes ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can access anything via a console/terminal. You may have to become root (sudo) to perform file operations on the root file system. (or did you mean /root/Cassandra ?)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to access /root/Cassandra.  By default /root is not accessable to normal users.  Try setting permissions on /root to 711 or 755 (chmod 711 /root).  You will also need make the Casandra directory writeable (chgrp users /root/Casasdda; chmod 770 /root/Casandra).  The use the default group of the userid your are downloading as.  It may be the same as the userid.

Comment: I doubt he wants to install it as /root/Cassandra, I think he meant /Cassandra, i.e. at the root of the fs.  If he wants to put it under /root/, which is usually the root user's home directory, then he has a misunderstanding.

Comment: If so the comments on changing access to the Casandra directory apply with /root applied.